# CSS Style a specific link

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

**Scenario:** I am in the process of creating a website for the company I work for. I need to follow their visual style guide so I'm creating a CSS file for the website.

**Question:** All the "more" links need to be in 11pt font while the body is in 12pt. Is there a way to specify that if the link is "more" that it will be styled in 11pt?

**Edit**: Is there anyway to do this without using a class? Based off the text instead?

**Summary**: I need to style specific links but I would not like to use classes to style them, maybe text instead?

Comment: Can you not just give those links a different class?

Comment: @Tom Walters, Without having to give them a seperate class is there any other way? What I mean by more is that the link says "more" (the text part), it can point to any webpage.

Comment: @Gage, the class has nothing to do with the href (where it points). In modern web creation, we use classes to separate things that are alike. If you're also making the html for the pages, it's not hard to add a class to the anchors you need styled.

Comment: @Nick Radford, K thanks for the input. Fairly new to using css and wasn't to sure how this was usually done. I'll just add the class to each more link.

Comment: @Gage, I usually hate referring people to it, but check out http://w3schools.com/css It's an /alright/ set of information, and easy to understand too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

HTML

```
<a href="whatever.html" class="more">More</a>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a.more {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"*Can you give those links CSS classes?*"

So, you could use something like:

```
<a class="more-link" href="http://clownlovers.com">MORE</a>
```

And thus you could style those with CSS along the lines of:

```
a.more-link {
    font-size:11px;
}
```

If you can't do that, then I think you could write a little javascript program to go through and change any such links to the font you want. That's kind of minimal to implement, but I think that's an ugly hack, particularly since on slower machines, you may even initially see the default font appear until js runs and shifts things.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see this method used in any answer so maybe some people find it useful:

```css
    a[href="link.html"]{
        //your styles
    }
```

Will apply those styles to every tag with a href of *"link.html"*, I'm not sure about the compatibility tho, so I'll keep looking into this, hope this helps!

Comment: <a> is not a class ... perhaps without the period?

Answer (score 1):

specify a class for more link.
for eg...

```
<a href="#" class="link">more</a>
```

In CSS:

Use..

```
body
{
 font-weight:13pt;
}
a.link
{
font-weight:11pt;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to use another class? Was hoping to use one css file throughout.

Comment: In this case.No need to use another class for different links.you can use single class.

Answer (score 1):

If the links are defined in existing declarations, as is probably the case, you'll have to enforce each and every rule with an `important` keyword.

HTML

```
<a href="link.html">Normal link</a>

<a href="link.html" class="more">More</a>
```

CSS

```
a:link {
   font-weight:12pt;
}

a.more:link, a.more:hover, a.more:visited {
   font-weight:11pt !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way for CSS to sift through content like that, but could use jQuery to find all anchors that have the word "more" in it and change it based on that:

```
$("a:contains('more')").css("font-size", "11pt");
```

Not a CSS solution, but this is pretty much the only way you could do what you are asking for. [Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/AjwSE/).

Comment: and if he has a link that contains the word 'rumored', it will also be changed. AFAIK, he's writing the css and the html, and should use the conventions in place (using classes).

Comment: @Nick I totally agree, was just offering another solution as he seemed to not like the class adding/changing route :)