# href link color is globalized, how can I change a specific link's color?

Tags: html, css

So I made am making a website with a lot of links, but I don't like the color changing after you clicked a link, so I added the following properties in my css.

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
} 
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
} 
a:hover   {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
} 
a:active  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
} 
a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This works and serves it's purpose, however, my NAV bar uses a switch link, and I need the text to be white. I tried making the specific text in the div white, using the `<font color="white>` and I tried making all links within my specific div white through css, but nothing seem's to work.

nav code:

```
<div class="div-right">
    <ul style="list-style: none;" class="menu">
       <li>
         <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeTab(0)" >Home</a>
         <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeTab(1)" >Projects</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Update your question with the current HTML code for the navbar you want to change.

Comment: @fyrye sorry, added it

Comment: what's the relation to php? and where's the js method?

Comment: HTML: `<a href='#' class='color'>test</a>` CSS: `a.color:link { color: red; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Style a specific link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428783/css-style-a-specific-link)

Comment: @icecub This worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a specific CSS to those `a` tags in the menu.

```
.div-right > ul > li > a {
    color: white;
}
```

Add more CSS in the same way if you want to `hover`, `visited` etc.